# Geometric Sum of the circumference of the layers of a cake

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, circles

The diameter of each successive layer of a wedding cake is 2/3 the previous layer. If the diameter of the first layer of a 5 layer cake is 15 inches, find the sum of the circumferences of all the layers.

So the text says the answer is $39.1\pi$. But that is the sum of the diameters of the cake. Can someone verify the answer key is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the circumference of a circle of diameter $d$ is $d\pi$. From the information given, we have that sum of circumferences is
\begin{align}
15\pi \left(1 + \frac{2}{3} + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4\right) \approx 39.1 \pi.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The answer key is correct.

The circumference of a layer with diameter $d$ is $C = \pi d$.  Since the diameter of each successive layer is $2/3$ that of the previous layer and the first layer is $15~\text{in}$, the sum of the circumferences of the five layers is 
$$15\pi~\text{in}\left[1 + \frac{2}{3} + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4\right]$$
Since the $n$th partial sum of a geometric series with initial term $a_1$ and common ratio $r$ is 
$$S_n = a_1 \frac{1 - r^n}{1 - r}$$
the sum of the circumferences is 
\begin{align*}
15\pi~\text{in}\left[1 + \frac{2}{3} + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4\right] & = 15\pi \cdot \dfrac{1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^5}{1 - \frac{2}{3}}\\
& = 15\pi~\text{in} \cdot \dfrac{1 - \frac{32}{243}}{\frac{1}{3}}\\
& = 45\pi~\text{in} \cdot \dfrac{211}{243}\\
& = 5\pi~\text{in} \cdot \frac{211}{27}\\
& = \frac{1055\pi}{27}~\text{in}\\
& \approx 39.1\pi~\text{in}
\end{align*}